# Trying to set usb debugging on Google Nexus tablet

Tags: android

I just bought googles Nexus7 7inch tablet with 16gb to test my app on. It has android version 4.2.7

I cannot figure out how to turn on USB debugging.
I ran the settings app.  I click on security and apps. but dod not see anything for enabling usb debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire **Developer Options** screen is now hidden from normal users since 4.2.

You need to first enable **Developer Options** by tapping **Build number** in **Settings/About phone** 7 times.

Then **Developer Options** will be enabled and you can enable **USB Debugging**

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

> On devices running Android 4.2, developer options are hidden by default, helping to create a better experience for users. You can reveal the developer options at any time by tapping 7 times on **Settings > About phone > Build number** on any compatible Android device.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you i would have never figured that out.

Comment: My tablet still isn't showing up with `adb devices`, is there something else required?  My phone shows up just fine...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I'm not 100% sure but you might need to reinstall/install the latest version of the [Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open settings
2. Open About Phone
3. Tap on Build number several times until you see a small popup with text "You are now a developer."

Now you should have Developer options in Settings. You should enable usb debugging in there