# Unable to install the Android USB driver on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, debugging, driver

So I want to use my new Nexus 5 for debugging my apps.
I tried to install the Android USB driver via the  [device manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7)
But my nexus is listed as portable device and uses the default windows driver.
How can I replace the windows `MTP-USB driver` with the android driver?
When I click update driver software und select `"\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"`, it tells me that the driver software is up-to-date.

Edit:
USB Debugging is already activated
Edit 2:
Sorry my fault there are actually two Nexus 5 in my Device Manager. The other one accepted the android driver.

Comment: You've turned on the USB Debugging option in Developer Settings on the device? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630670/trying-to-set-usb-debugging-on-google-nexus-tablet/17630704#17630704

Comment: From command prompt when you give "adb devices" without quotes are you able to view the connected device?

Answer (score 18):

First you'd want to make sure you device is in 'debug mode' or 'usb debugging' - set through development settings in your phone's 'system settings'

then run `adb devices` from your adt-bundle folder/platform-tools to see if it got your device.

Edit: 
if it doesn't work try, from your 'drivers' tab-
Update Driver -> Browse for driver software on my computer -> Let me pick from a list of device drivers from my computer -> Have Disk -> Navigate to your usb_driver folder

*Notice the extra step near the end, you don't submit the folder in the "Browse for driver software on my computer" tab*

Comment: Try, from your drivers directory - Update Driver -> Browse for driver software on my computer -> Let me pick from a list of device drivers from my computer -> Have Disk -> *Navigate to your usb_driver folder*    
|*Notice the extra step near the end, you don't enter the folder in the "Browser for driver software on my computer" tab*

Answer (score 0):

1. download this usb driver: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/EeePAD/nexus7/usb_driver_r06_windows.zip
2. go to the device manager , right click the nexus device and choose properties, choose "hardware" and then choose update your driver , choose manualy and pick the folder you opend the zip file to and press apply.
3. open your setting in nexus . go to : "about the device" , at to the bottom of the page and press it strong text7 times .
4. open the developers menu and enable debug with usb.
5. finally press storage from the setting menu and click the menu that apears at the top left corner. press the connect usb to the computer, choose the second option (PTP).

that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got the drivers installed for my nexus 5 was by following these instructions but I had to turn off my phone and do the steps below but for following the first set of instructions for the link below:[Nexus 5 Driver installation instructions](http://www.android.gs/download-and-install-google-nexus-5-usb-drivers-adb-fastboot/)

power off your phone.
press and hold Volume Down and Power buttons simultaneously
- an Android robot will show up and the Fastboot Mode text is listed.
connect the Nexus 5 to your PC via USB Cable.

After doing this the drivers installed but had a yell warning sign. However I was still able to get it to take commands and for it to be seen by the ADB devices command. I currently am using windows 7, and I have the adb setup in my environment variables so I can run commands from the command line.

In the command line **before you call the adb devices, make sure you navigate to the android platform tools folder '\Android\android-studio\sdk\platform-tools** then from here call the adb devices and you will know for sure if your device is being detected!

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight the key step that solved the problem for me using a Nexus 5.

Follow the steps by Neeraj, just replacing the first one by the drivers in http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Key point is to make sure you change the usb connection to use PTP and try to install the driver from the Nexus 5 under other devices.

That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another related issue:

Every time you connect a device through USB 3.0, Windows 7 automatically installs its own drivers that can't be updated. Removing them does nothing, as they will just be immediately installed again upon reconnection.

To get get around this, you need just need to use a USB 2.0 slot.

Answer (score 0):

To allow usb debugging for an lg f60 d390 in Android Studio I had to install LG PC Suit.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, Uninstall the existing driver. Then your device will be listed under Android Device -> Composite ADB interface in device manager. You then can follow steps to update the Google - USB driver.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me.

Switch the USB port you use.

For whatever reason once I did this Windows recognized my device.

Comment: This works me for every new android device https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/installing-android-debug-bridge-adb-usb-driver-on-windows